# Buttons not accessible in Wpf Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a function in Codebehind c#
The Code is Like :

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{ 
   // ...
}
```

In this Function i have to set the visibility of a button to `true` :

```
Runrc.IsEnabled = true;
```

But I get no intellisense for this button in that function, and it's giving me a error .

Comment: Hey Noctis When i removed static ,i am able to access the function !!
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Yep, @Sriram was right on the money. You should mark it as answered :)

Comment: yea i am trying i cannot mark it answer within 8 minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the method is `static`. You cannot access a instance member in static method without its object reference.

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)//Remove static
{ 
   // access your button here
}
```

If you're not familiar with static members you can read it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Sriram , you maded my day :) :D